# "undefined reference to `_head_libpython27_a'"

Tags: python, windows, mingw, setup.py

So, I've been trying to install py-notify (now I've been running into the same problems with trying to install cython), but I've run into a problem that I wasn't able to fix with Google this time (the only results are for this question now...).
First, I was running into this problem: http://pastebin.com/0hs6ngsj
After following the procedure on [this page](http://wiki.cython.org/InstallingOnWindows#Troubleshooting) to create the file `libpython27.a` (which seemed to be what is required), and putting it into `C:\Python27\libs\`, I now get this error instead:

```
C:\...>easy_install py-notify
Searching for py-notify
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/py-notify/
Reading http://home.gna.org/py-notify/
Reading http://download.gna.org/py-notify/
Best match: py-notify 0.3.1
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/py-notify/py-notify-0.3.1.tar.gz#md5=58428761bc196bf9b1f1d930991ee3ca
Processing py-notify-0.3.1.tar.gz
Running py-notify-0.3.1\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\nightkev\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-qfiohj\py-notify-0.3.1\egg-dist-tmp-zoe6ad
C:\Python27\libs\libpython27.a(dwtms01015.o):(.idata$7+0x0): undefined reference to `_head_libpython27_a'
C:\Python27\libs\libpython27.a(dwtms00254.o):(.idata$7+0x0): undefined reference to `_head_libpython27_a'
C:\Python27\libs\libpython27.a(dwtms00713.o):(.idata$7+0x0): undefined reference to `_head_libpython27_a'
C:\Python27\libs\libpython27.a(dwtms00221.o):(.idata$7+0x0): undefined reference to `_head_libpython27_a'
C:\Python27\libs\libpython27.a(dwtms00008.o):(.idata$7+0x0): undefined reference to `_head_libpython27_a'
C:\Python27\libs\libpython27.a(dwtms00338.o):(.idata$7+0x0): more undefined references to `_head_libpython27_a' follow
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
dllwrap: gcc exited with status 1
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'dllwrap' failed with exit status 1
```

Python info:

```
ActivePython 2.7.2.5 (ActiveState Software Inc.) based on
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 24 2011, 12:21:10) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
```

OS: `Windows 7 Professional Edition x64`
I'm unsure what other information I might need to provide.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. The best solution I could come up with was to scrap MinGW and install Visual Studio. For Python 2.7 you need Visual Studio C++ Express Edition 2008 (note that 2010 won't work!)

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2008-editions/express

If you come up with an answer that works with MinGW please let me know.